# Connection refused when trying to push LFS Files into Gerrit - Git LFS

Tags: git, gerrit, git-lfs

I'm currently working with Git LFS and Gerrit.
Everying seems to be fine, till I try to push LFS files to the gerrit server.
I got the following error:

```
LFS: Put http://<localhost>:3001/plugins/lfs/content/default/2133123fd: dial tcp <localhost>:3001: connect: connection refused error: failed to push some refs to 'http://<user>@<localhost>:3001/lfs'
```

I have try a lot of configurations and I don't really know what is causing this problem.

These are my configurations.

**GERRIT AND LFS**

**cat $gerrit_path/etc/gerrit.config**

```
[auth]
    type = development_become_any_account
    gitBasicAuthPolicy = HTTP
[lfs]
        plugin = lfs
```

**cat $gerrit_path/etc/lfs.config**

```
[storage]
    backend = fs
[fs]
        directory = /home/<user>/workspace/gerrit_2.15.6
```

**LOCAL PROJECT**

**cat .git/config**

```
[lfs]
        access = basic
        locksverify = false
        url = http://<user>:<password>@<localhost>:3001/lfs/info/lfs

[filter "lfs"]
        clean = git-lfs clean -- %f
        smudge = git-lfs smudge -- %f
        process = git-lfs filter-process
        required = true
```

**cat .gitattributes**

```
*.tar filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
```

The gerrit I'm using is not on production, I'm just making some testing to see the implantation (so basically gerrit has the default configurations).
I have already tested the HTTP connection and the SSH. I can push and pull normal files with both of these. The problem comes when I try to push LFS files.

I think the problem could be the local git-lfs extension, because if I do  **git lfs uninstall** on the local project, the push goes through, but the object isn't really upload to the gerrit server (just the reference).

Thank you so much!

**Extra data:**

Gerrit version: 2.15.6

Git LFS extension version: git-lfs/2.10.0 (GitHub; linux amd64; go 1.13.4)

Gerrit LFS plugin: 2.15

Also did the following configuration on All-project on gerrit:
[Configure Gerrit with Git LFS examples please](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53102564/configure-gerrit-with-git-lfs-examples-please)

Comment: Looking at "url = http://<user>:<password>@<localhost>:3001/lfs/info/lfs" I assume your repository is named "lfs", is this correct?

Comment: yes, it is correct

Comment: Have you modified that error and the configuration you posted in anyway from what's actually written in console? Have you restarted gerrit after adding the LFS plugin and configuration?

Comment: The only thing I edited from the error are the parameters between "< >". and Yes I restarted the gerrit server after doing all this process.

Comment: I have read something about the "git-lfs-authenticate". They suggest to run this command          **ssh <user>@<localhost> git-lfs-authenticate lfs_project.git**    
But if I try to run the command I got the error            **bash: git-lfs-authenticate: command not found** . I don't know if this could be the problem

Comment: Another note, when I installed gerrit with the command **java -jar gerrit-2.15.6.war init --batch -d ~/gerrit_example** . I didn't use the default folder for it's installation, instead I used another one with the "-d". I'm not sure if this got something to do with the problem before.

Comment: In my <repository>/.git/config file I have: [lfs "https://USER@GERRIT-SERVER/REPOSITORY.git/info/lfs"] access = basic. A little bit different that yours.

Comment: It shows the same error than before. Just tells me to add locksveryfy = false. besides that, is the same output message.
"Remote "origin" does not support the LFS locking API. Consider disabling it with:
  $ git config lfs.https://localhost/zip_lfs.git/info/lfs.locksverify false"

Comment: Do you have httpS protocol configured in your gerrit server?
Maybe, this could be the problem.

Comment: Do  you have an answser fix of this?